# Microsoft Teams -- Where's the meeting tab?

Tags: office-365, microsoft-teams

According to Microsoft's Documentation (I can't add more than 2 links due to rep, so Google `Microsoft Teams schedule meeting`, click on the first result titled `Meetings and calling - Office Support` and expand the "What's a private scheduled meeting?" section), you can schedule a private meeting using the calendar icon on the left-hand side.

I don't see this icon. I see Activity, Chat, Teams and Files at the top, and at the bottom, Feedback and my Avatar.

Is the icon something I need to enable? Something that could possibly be restricted by the type of Office 365 subscription we have (Education - Faculty and Staff)? I can't see any settings in the Teams app / website, and private scheduled meetings is turned on in the admin section of the Office 365 portal:

[image: Private meetings turned on]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Buried on a [Microsoft support page](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Known-issues-for-Microsoft-Teams-04b35d1b-bdca-420a-991b-878da5157650) is this section:

> **Issue**: Missing Meetings icon in the left nav bar
>
> **Symptom**: The Meetings icon on the app bar is currently only enabled for users whose mailbox is on Office 365 multi-tenant and a select few dedicated users whose mailbox location can be discovered using Exchange auto discovery. Microsoft Teams does not yet support mailboxes housed in Exchange on-premises and Exchange Dedicated. This is under investigation; however, there is no timing for delivering this capability.
>
> **Workaround**: No workaround.

So essentially this feature won't show up if your mailbox is hosted on-site. It's being investigated, but with no timeline for getting it working.